# Chrome dev tools reports nonexistent dimensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

This angular component is obviously 0x0 and not even on the DOM as it seems, yet dev tools tells me it covers the whole screen. This problem appears occasionally when I try to debug web apps - I am told the element is the entire screen's height, yet its barely 60px.

What is causing this?

Comment: Without [MCVE](/help/mcve) the only idea I can think of is that it's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm its a semi-frequent error I normally get when building angular apps, and I do not know how to share a problematic big project in a helpful manner in SO. If you know of a way to share framework problems, feel free to tell me.